# Method to return the equation of a straight line given two points

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class `Point`, consisting of a point with x and y coordinates, and I have to write a method that computes and returns the equation of a straight line joining a `Point` object and another `Point` object that is passed as an argument (`my_point.get_straight_line(my_point2)`. I know how to calculate that on paper with y-y<sub>1</sub> = m(x-x<sub>1</sub>) and I already have a method `my_point.slope(my_point2)` to compute `m`, but I can't really wrap my head around how to translate the equation to Python. Here's the entire class:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,initx,inity):
        self.x = initx
        self.y = inity

    def getx(self):
        return self.x

    def gety(self):
        return self.y

    def negx(self):
        return -(self.x)

    def negy(self):
        return -(self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'x=' + str(self.x) + ', y=' + str(self.y)

    def halfway(self,target):
        midx = (self.x + target.x) / 2
        midy = (self.y + target.y) / 2
        return Point(midx, midy)

    def distance(self,target):
        xdiff = target.x - self.x
        ydiff = target.y - self.y
        dist = math.sqrt(xdiff**2 + ydiff**2)
        return dist

    def reflect_x(self):
        return Point(self.negx(),self.y)

    def reflect_y(self):
        return Point(self.x,self.negy())

    def reflect_x_y(self):
        return Point(self.negx(),self.negy())

    def slope_from_origin(self):
        if self.x == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return self.y / self.x

    def slope(self,target):
        if target.x == self.x:
            return None
        else:
            m = (target.y - self.y) / (target.x - self.x)
            return m
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I figured it out with an equation that computes `c` and then just returns it in a string along with `self.slope(target)`! This turned out to be way less complicated than I thought.

```
def get_line_to(self,target):
    c = -(self.slope(target)*self.x - self.y)
    return 'y = ' + str(self.slope(target)) + 'x + ' + str(c)
```

Comment: What you have looks good. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I can't really figure out which values out of `self.x`, `self.y`, `target.x` and `target.y` would be each value in the equation, and how to formulate it in order to calculate c.

Comment: `self.x` is x, `target.x` is x1. or vice versa. who cares! as long as you're consistent one way or the other.

Answer (score 38):

```
from numpy import ones,vstack
from numpy.linalg import lstsq
points = [(1,5),(3,4)]
x_coords, y_coords = zip(*points)
A = vstack([x_coords,ones(len(x_coords))]).T
m, c = lstsq(A, y_coords)[0]
print("Line Solution is y = {m}x + {c}".format(m=m,c=c))
```

but really your method should be fine ...

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: Could you edit the example to be python 3 friendly? I.e. parentheses

Comment: Isn't it an overkill using least squares to solve a mathematically solvable equation with exactly one solution?

Answer (score 31):

Let's assume that we have the following points:

> P0: ( x0 = 100, y0 = 240 )
>
> P1: ( x1 = 400, y1 = 265 )

We can compute the coefficients of the line y = a*x + b that connects the two points using the **polyfit** method from **numpy**.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the known points
x = [100, 400]
y = [240, 265]

# Calculate the coefficients. This line answers the initial question. 
coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

# Print the findings
print('a =', coefficients[0])
print('b =', coefficients[1])

# Let's compute the values of the line...
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
x_axis = np.linspace(0,500,100)
y_axis = polynomial(x_axis)

# ...and plot the points and the line
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.plot( x[0], y[0], 'go' )
plt.plot( x[1], y[1], 'go' )
plt.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

a = 0.0833333333333

b = 231.666666667

[image]

---

For installing numpy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html

Comment: `np.polyfit` is deprecated from numpy 1.4. prefer using `Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg)` for versions above.

Answer (score 24):

I think you are making pretty advanced code, but you are making it complicated.  Here is a function that can do that:

```python
from decimal import Decimal


def lin_equ(l1, l2):
    """Line encoded as l=(x,y)."""
    m = Decimal((l2[1] - l1[1])) / Decimal(l2[0] - l1[0])
    c = (l2[1] - (m * l2[0]))
    return m, c

# Example Usage:
lin_equ((-40, 30,), (20, 45))

# Result: (Decimal('0.25'), Decimal('40.00'))
```

Comment: What does the decimal module do for you other than guarantee floating point type?

Comment: @Sledge : even that can be accomplished by merely using the built-in `float()`

Comment: Can throw DivisionByZero

Comment: use decimal in case you are working with very large numbers otherwise float() in fine

Answer (score 5):

I cleaned it up a bit; see what you think.

```
def slope(dx, dy):
    return (dy / dx) if dx else None

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return '({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def halfway(self, target):
        midx = (self.x + target.x) / 2
        midy = (self.y + target.y) / 2
        return Point(midx, midy)

    def distance(self, target):
        dx = target.x - self.x
        dy = target.y - self.y
        return (dx*dx + dy*dy) ** 0.5

    def reflect_x(self):
        return Point(-self.x,self.y)

    def reflect_y(self):
        return Point(self.x,-self.y)

    def reflect_x_y(self):
        return Point(-self.x, -self.y)

    def slope_from_origin(self):
        return slope(self.x, self.y)

    def slope(self, target):
        return slope(target.x - self.x, target.y - self.y)

    def y_int(self, target):       # <= here's the magic
        return self.y - self.slope(target)*self.x

    def line_equation(self, target):
        slope = self.slope(target)

        y_int = self.y_int(target)
        if y_int < 0:
            y_int = -y_int
            sign = '-'
        else:
            sign = '+'

        return 'y = {}x {} {}'.format(slope, sign, y_int)

    def line_function(self, target):
        slope = self.slope(target)
        y_int = self.y_int(target)
        def fn(x):
            return slope*x + y_int
        return fn
```

and here are some use examples:

```
a = Point(2., 2.)
b = Point(4., 3.)

print(a)                   # => (2.0, 2.0)
print(repr(b))             # => Point(4.0, 3.0)
print(a.halfway(b))        # => (3.0, 2.5)

print(a.slope(b))          # => 0.5
print(a.y_int(b))          # => 1.0
print(a.line_equation(b))  # => y = 0.5x + 1.0

line = a.line_function(b)
print(line(x=6.))          # => 4.0
```

Comment: It looks good, but I'd like an explanation of what each part does exactly and why it's important, and how the .format() method works because I've never seen it before. Sorry if I'm asking embarrassingly stupid questions, I've never really done any programming before getting started with Python!

Comment: @reggaelizard Sometimes it is better to look up the doc for yourself, check out [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Answer (score 3):

```
class Line(object):

    def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
        self.coor1 = coor1
        self.coor2 = coor2


    def distance(self):
        x1,y1 = self.coor1
        x2,y2 = self.coor2
        return ((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)**0.5    

    def slope(self):
        x1,x2 = self.coor1
        y1,y2 = self.coor2
        return (float(y2-y1))/(x2-x1)
```

Comment: in slope method you did `x1,x2 = self.coor1` which is wrong. it should be x1,y1= and same for x2,y2=, indeed your method does not return the right value, to return the correct number that typo has to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[1,1,2,2]
#l=[x1,y1,x2,y2]
y0=l[3]-l[1]
x0=l[0]-l[2]
c = l[1]*l[2]-l[0]*l[3]
if(x0>0):
    print(y0,"x","+",x0,"y=",c)
else:
    print(y0,"x",x0,"y=",c)
```