# limit the extent of a line or polynomial plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32712028/4288043) from user @funk shows how to plot a line with matplotlib. This was the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the known points
x = [100, 400]
y = [240, 265]

# Calculate the coefficients. This line answers the initial question. 
coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

# Print the findings
print 'a =', coefficients[0]
print 'b =', coefficients[1]

# Let's compute the values of the line...
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
x_axis = np.linspace(0,500,100)
y_axis = polynomial(x_axis)

# ...and plot the points and the line
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.plot( x[0], y[0], 'go' )
plt.plot( x[1], y[1], 'go' )
plt.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

I want to limit the plotting of the line so that it does not extend below 90 or above 410. Have tried changing numbers on the `linspace` line but that also changes the axes. How do you limit the extent of the plotted line without it having any impact on the axes?

Comment: Change `x_axis` to `x_axis = np.linspace(90,410,100)`?

Comment: Thanks but that changes the axes. If you try it you will see. I need the axes to stay the same but just the line to be clipped

Comment: no, you should draw the line as that, and do `plt.xlim(0, 500)` prior to `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the best way to do this is to set `xlim` and `ylim` after you plot the points. But...

If you really want to drive the limits entirely by the plotting of a line, you could plot the line with `alpha=0.0`.  Then you could replot the part you want to see using a visible `alpha`.  Like this:

[image]

```
# ...and plot the points and the line
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, alpha=0.0)
rfilter = (x_axis>100) & (x_axis<400)
plt.plot(x_axis[rfilter], y_axis[rfilter])
plt.plot( x[0], y[0], 'go' )
plt.plot( x[1], y[1], 'go' )
plt.grid('on')
```

My reasoning for using `alpha=0.0` is that you're ambivalent about the extent of the line: in some ways you want the full extent of the line to drive the plot, but you just don't want to see the full extent.  So since it's about not seeing it, I set the alpha.  If I have this logic wrong, and you have some other goal in mind, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. Can see that the `rfilter` variable is an array of booleans which on the next line chops the ends off `x_axis` and `y_axis`. Had a play with alpha to see what it is doing, is less obvious. When I set it to 0.1 for example, it leaves the unwanted bits of the lines there bit in a much lighter shade. Will leave alpha at 0.0.