# Reducing 3D Interpolation size based off radial components

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have the following data which represnt points in a 3D grid:

```
x = array([ 0, 0.08885313,  0.05077321,  0.05077321,  0.03807991,  0.03807991,
        0.03807991,  0.02538661,  0.02538661,  0.0126933 ,  0.0126933 ,
       -0.        , -0.        , -0.0126933 , -0.0126933 , -0.02538661,
       -0.02538661, -0.02538661, -0.03807991, -0.05077321, -0.05077321,
       -0.05077321, -0.06346652, -0.07615982, -0.11423973, -0.12693304,
       -0.13962634])
y = array([ 0, -0.15231964, -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.08885313, -0.10154643,
       -0.12693304, -0.07615982, -0.08885313, -0.07615982, -0.08885313,
       -0.07615982, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.10154643, -0.07615982,
       -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.11423973,
       -0.12693304, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.12693304,
       -0.11423973])
z = array([ 0, 1.21839241, 0.78673339, 1.21839241, 0.70318648, 0.82850684,
       0.96078945, 0.64748854, 0.71014872, 0.63356406, 0.71711096,
       0.65445078, 0.77977115, 0.73103545, 0.77977115, 0.68926199,
       0.73799769, 1.19750569, 0.85635581, 0.84243133, 0.96078945,
       1.02344963, 0.93294048, 0.97471393, 1.24624138, 1.20446793,
       1.22535466])
```

I am attempting to fit a surface to these points. I want to fit the surface such that it only extends between the data points and the origin.

I have tried the following code:

```
data = np.array([x, y, z]).T 
  
# Define mathematical function for curve fitting 
def func(xy, a, b, c, d, e, f): 
    x, y = xy 
    return a + b*x + c*y + d*x**2 + e*y**2 + f*x*y 
  
# Perform curve fitting 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (x, y), z) 
  
# Print optimized parameters 
print(popt) 
  
# Create 3D plot of the data points and the fitted curve 
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='blue') 
x_range = np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, 50) 
y_range = np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, 50) 
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range) 
Z = func((X, Y), *popt) 
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='red', alpha=0.5) 

ax.set_xlim([-0.2, 0.2])  
ax.set_ylim([-0.2, 0.2])
ax.set_zlim([0,1.2])

plt.show()
```

This code gives me the following plot. I have drawn in blue lines where I would like the interpolation to be between. How would I add two different angles that would limit my plot in the radial direction so that the interpolation is between these lines?

[image]

**Edit**

Using the helpful answer provided I now am getting the following plot. However as you can see beyond the limit of y being -0.3 the interpolated surface begins to go down again. Is there a way I can apply a constraint such that the interpolation after my data only increases. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limiting lines seem to lie to the left and to the right from the zero-point (0, 0, 0), across the x-axis. This means that two points with the minimum and maximum values of x could be used to define both of those lines. You could find their coefficients with [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html), like in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21566184/3715182). The XY-projections of the lines can be used to set a limiting condition (with [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)) on the surface being plotted:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import ones, vstack
from numpy.linalg import lstsq

x = np.array([ 0, 0.08885313,  0.05077321,  0.05077321,  0.03807991,  0.03807991,
        0.03807991,  0.02538661,  0.02538661,  0.0126933 ,  0.0126933 ,
       -0.        , -0.        , -0.0126933 , -0.0126933 , -0.02538661,
       -0.02538661, -0.02538661, -0.03807991, -0.05077321, -0.05077321,
       -0.05077321, -0.06346652, -0.07615982, -0.11423973, -0.12693304,
       -0.13962634])
y = np.array([ 0, -0.15231964, -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.08885313, -0.10154643,
       -0.12693304, -0.07615982, -0.08885313, -0.07615982, -0.08885313,
       -0.07615982, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.10154643, -0.07615982,
       -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.11423973,
       -0.12693304, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.12693304,
       -0.11423973])
z = np.array([ 0, 1.21839241, 0.78673339, 1.21839241, 0.70318648, 0.82850684,
       0.96078945, 0.64748854, 0.71014872, 0.63356406, 0.71711096,
       0.65445078, 0.77977115, 0.73103545, 0.77977115, 0.68926199,
       0.73799769, 1.19750569, 0.85635581, 0.84243133, 0.96078945,
       1.02344963, 0.93294048, 0.97471393, 1.24624138, 1.20446793,
       1.22535466])

# The data set seems to be within two boundaries located to the left and to the right from the (0, 0, 0) point across the x-axis
# Find the maximum and minimum x values
i_max, = np.where(np.isclose(x, np.max(x)))
i_min, = np.where(np.isclose(x, np.min(x)))
x_max = x[i_max][0]
x_min = x[i_min][0]

# Find the corresponding y values (i.e. y values of those points where x is maximum)
y_max = y[i_max][0]
y_min = y[i_min][0]

# Function finding 2D-line coefficients, based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21566184/3715182
def line_coeffs(points):
    x_coords, y_coords = zip(*points)
    A = vstack([x_coords, ones(len(x_coords))]).T
    # y = a*x + b
    a, b = lstsq(A, y_coords, rcond=None)[0]
    return (a, b)

# Find coefficients of the two lines "limiting" all points left and right across the x-axis in the XY-plane
k1_max, k2_max = line_coeffs([(x_max, y_max), (0, 0)])
k1_min, k2_min = line_coeffs([(x_min, y_min), (0, 0)])
  
# Define mathematical function for curve fitting 
def func(xy, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    x, y = xy
    return a + b*x + c*y + d*x**2 + e*y**2 + f*x*y
  
# Perform curve fitting 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (x, y), z)
  
# Print optimized parameters 
print(popt)
  
# Create 3D plot of the data points and the fitted curve 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='blue')
x_range = np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, 1000)
y_range = np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, 1000)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
Z = func((X, Y), *popt)
# Limit the surface with a condition, forcing its XY-projections to be within the area limited by two lines
ax.plot_surface(np.where(X >= (Y - k2_min)/k1_min, np.where(X <= (Y - k2_max)/k1_max, X, np.nan), np.nan), Y, Z, color='red', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlim([-0.2, 0.2])
ax.set_ylim([-0.2, 0.2])
ax.set_zlim([0,1.2])

ax.set_xlabel('x')  
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. When I plot it instead with the lower y limit being -0.3, the plot then seems to start going down again. Is there any way I can change the fitting so that it will continue upwards. (question has been edited to reflect this)

Comment: Sure, you can always try some other fitting, resulting in that surface going upwards, for example something like `x/(b + a) + y/(c + a) + d*x**2 + e*y**2 + x*y/f`. But I'm afraid I cannot tell you whether this fitting suits you best. The choice of the fitting function depends on the purpose of your interpolation and on the nature of your data as well.