# 3D interpolation of data in python limiting the fitted function to only be increasing in z

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have the following data:

```
x = array([ 0, 0.08885313,  0.05077321,  0.05077321,  0.03807991,  0.03807991,
        0.03807991,  0.02538661,  0.02538661,  0.0126933 ,  0.0126933 ,
       -0.        , -0.        , -0.0126933 , -0.0126933 , -0.02538661,
       -0.02538661, -0.02538661, -0.03807991, -0.05077321, -0.05077321,
       -0.05077321, -0.06346652, -0.07615982, -0.11423973, -0.12693304,
       -0.13962634])
y = array([ 0, -0.15231964, -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.08885313, -0.10154643,
       -0.12693304, -0.07615982, -0.08885313, -0.07615982, -0.08885313,
       -0.07615982, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.10154643, -0.07615982,
       -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.11423973,
       -0.12693304, -0.10154643, -0.08885313, -0.17770625, -0.12693304,
       -0.11423973])
z = array([ 0, 1.21839241, 0.78673339, 1.21839241, 0.70318648, 0.82850684,
       0.96078945, 0.64748854, 0.71014872, 0.63356406, 0.71711096,
       0.65445078, 0.77977115, 0.73103545, 0.77977115, 0.68926199,
       0.73799769, 1.19750569, 0.85635581, 0.84243133, 0.96078945,
       1.02344963, 0.93294048, 0.97471393, 1.24624138, 1.20446793,
       1.22535466])
```

I have used the following code which fits a surface in the form of points in the (x, y, z) space to my data.

```
# Find the maximum and minimum x values
i_max, = np.where(np.isclose(x, np.max(x)))
i_min, = np.where(np.isclose(x, np.min(x)))
x_max = x[i_max][0]
x_min = x[i_min][0]

# Find the corresponding y values (i.e. y values of those points where x is maximum)
y_max = y[i_max][0]
y_min = y[i_min][0]

# Function finding 2D-line coefficients, based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21566184/3715182
def line_coeffs(points):
    x_coords, y_coords = zip(*points)
    A = vstack([x_coords, ones(len(x_coords))]).T
    # y = a*x + b
    a, b = lstsq(A, y_coords, rcond=None)[0]
    return (a, b)

# Find coefficients of the two lines "limiting" all points left and right across the x-axis in the XY-plane
k1_max, k2_max = line_coeffs([(x_max, y_max), (0, 0)])
k1_min, k2_min = line_coeffs([(x_min, y_min), (0, 0)])

# Define mathematical function for curve fitting 
def func(xy, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    x, y = xy
    return a + b*x + c*y + d*x**2 + e*y**2 + f*x*y

# Create a grid of points over the surface
x_fill = np.linspace(-0.2, 0.2, 40)
y_fill = np.linspace(-0.3, 0, 40)
X_fill, Y_fill = np.meshgrid(x_fill, y_fill)

# Evaluate the function at each point on the surface
Z_fill = func((X_fill, Y_fill), *popt)

# Plot the data points and the filled surface
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='blue', label='Data Points')

ax.scatter(np.where(X_fill >= (Y_fill - k2_min)/k1_min, np.where(X_fill <= (Y_fill - k2_max)/k1_max, X_fill, np.nan), np.nan), Y_fill, Z_fill, color='red', alpha=0.5, s= 2)

ax.set_xlim([-0.2, 0.2])
ax.set_ylim([-0.3, 0.2])
ax.set_zlim([0, 1.2])

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

This gives my the following plot which is shown at two different angles:

[image]

[image]

You can see that the red points fit my blue data points well. However, I would be expected the data to continue upwards rather than going back down around y=-0.3. How can I limit (or change) my fitting function so that the function is continuously increasing in z. I would expect something a bit more like a section of the following plot (only between 2 angles):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third graph you posted looks like it has rotational symmetry around (0, 0), so I would suggest fitting a function which has rotational symmetry. An easy way to do this is to convert from cartesian into polar coordinates, and ignore theta.

Before taking this approach, it's useful to check if the data passes the vertical line test in polar form to make sure that discarding theta like this will work.

[image: graph of Z versus R]

This looks more or less okay.

The graph doesn't look completely straight, so let's transform into polar form, then fit a quadratic.

Define the function:

```
def func(xy, a, b, c):
    x, y = xy
    r = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    theta = np.arctan2(x, y)
    return a*(r - b)**2 + c
```

Fit it:

```
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [x, y], z)
```

The result is a pretty good fit, but it fails one of your requirements.

[image: non monotonic with respect to r]

The function is not monotonic with respect to x or y. In other words, as you move out from the center, it goes up, then back down again. However, this is fixable. We know where the peak of the parabola is. At radius `b`, the parabola reaches a peak of `c`, and goes back down. We can change this function to only have half a parabola, and fill in the rest with a straight line.

```
def func(xy, a, b, c):
    x, y = xy
    r = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    theta = np.arctan2(x, y)
    parabola = a*(r - b)**2 + c
    return np.where(r <= b, parabola, c)
```

This produces the following extrapolation:

[image: extrapolation is monotonic]

This gives you the same quality of fit with fewer parameters and more control.

You could also try a version which drops rotational symmetry by including a theta term:

```
def func(xy, a, b, c, d):
    x, y = xy
    r = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    theta = np.arctan2(x, y)
    parabola = a*(r - b)**2 + c + d*np.sin(theta)
    return np.where(r <= b, parabola, c)
```

I didn't find that this added much accuracy.

#### Comparisons of methods

- JJacquelin's exponential

  Code:

  ```
  def func(xy, a, b):
      x, y = xy
      r = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
      return a*(1-np.exp(-b*r))
  ```

  Visualization:

  [image: exponential fit]

  Parameters: 2

  RMSE: 0.03141 (Note: slightly lower error obtained due to using `curve_fit()` to fit the function rather than linear approximation.)
- HOBE's upside down Gaussian. (Note: changed the definition to add constant/scaling term to match your dataset.)

  Code:

  ```
  def func(xy, a, sigma, c):
      x, y = xy
      exponent = -((x ** 2 + y ** 2) / (2*sigma**2))
      return -a*(1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2))*np.exp(exponent) + c
  ```

  Visualization:

  [image: upside down Gaussian]

  Parameters: 3

  RMSE: 0.03965
- My half-parabola.

  Parameters: 3

  RMSE: 0.02933
- My half-parabola adding a theta term.

  Parameters: 4

  RMSE: 0.02539
- Elliptical cone

  Code:

  ```
  def func(xy, a, b, c, d):
      x, y = xy
      return np.sqrt(a**2 * ( (x**2/b**2) + (y**2/c**2)  )+d)
  ```

  Visualization:

  [image: elliptical cone]

  Parameters: 4

  RMSE: 0.08512
- Stretched exponential

  Explanation: this is a combination of JJacquelin's method with the cone method, allowing the exponential to slope off at different rates in x and y.

  ```
  def func(xy, a, b, c):
      x, y = xy
      r = np.sqrt(x**2/b**2 + y**2/c**2)
      return a*(1-np.exp(-r))
  ```

  Visualization:

  [image: stretched exponential]

  RMSE: 0.02870

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. Could perhaps an elliptical cone be fitted in the form `np.sqrt(a**2 * ( (x**2/b**2) + (y**2/c**2)  )+d)`, how would that stack up against the other methods?

Comment: @jim_athon It gets an RMSE of 0.08512, which is higher than the other methods. It doesn't seem to go through 0,0,0 - it seems to sacrifice fit on that point to improve the fit from R 0.10 to 0.20. The method gains some accuracy by treating x and y differently, but loses some by being forced to draw a straight line through the data.

Comment: @jim_athon Actually, now that I think about it, you could combine JJacquelin's exponential with the cone method to allow it to slope off at different rates in X and Y. This gives the best error so far for a 3 parameter fit.

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that the fitting function is continuously increasing in z one should choose a kind of function intrinsically increasing. Logistic function or exponential function are good candidates among many possiblities.

For example with a function of exponential kind :

[image]

NOTE : The fitting is very simple thanks to a method which isn't iterative and doesn't need initial guess of the parameters. General principle in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . Details of the numerical calculus below :

[image]

Of course one can use as well a classical method of non-linear regression implemented in commercial software. The result : a=4.969968 ; b=2.025636 ; RMSE=0.0314 is so close to above than the very small difference is not visible on the graph.